# Searchable ListView with checkboxes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a searchable ListView of adjectives (in Dutch) with checkboxes next to them. The list is searchable with an edittext on top. I'd like to be able to search the list and remember which checkboxes are checked and which are not. So when I search something, check it and go back to the complete list, it still has to be checked. Next, I have to be able to obtain what the user has checked.

The code I have so far: the [Activity (cs)](http://pastebin.com/nQyi4pKm), its [ContentView (xml)](http://pastebin.com/00Ba059D) and the [ListItem (xml)](http://pastebin.com/bzCWdd4m).

I'm sorry for the broad question and not providing specific chunks of code, but I don't know how to go about this. Can someone help me or steer me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

filter your **list** like below in on text change, add text change **listener**.

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
```

and when user check something from **list**, get a text from **list view** at then again check its index in the original list. I hope you get it, let me know if any confusion.

Comment: please note this is java code, you can implement similar functionality in c#. means can filter listview based on characters.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of remembering which checkboxes are checked and which are not?

Comment: when user select check box, get index of that check box and then get String value at that check box, and then you have to search this string in your original list to find its original index and select check box at that locations. means you will have two arrays with same data.